# Using WrapLayout with multiple adjacent JPanels is causing Panel sizing issues

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have 3 adjacent JPanels that each use WrapLayout to display a variable number of 1x16 grids.

It works great for the panel which contains the most 1x16 grids, however, the other two panels' dimensions seem to be determined by the panel that contains the most 1x16 grids. If, for example, panels 1 and 2 have only one 1x16 grid respectively, but panel 3 has ten 1x16 grids spread across two rows, then panel 1 and 2 both have a 1x16 grid-sized empty space beneath their respective 1x16 grids.

I basically want to get each panel's resizing to operate independently of the other panels. I've looked through camickr's src code for WrapLayout and can't quite work out what I should change to get the desired result.

In terms of code, it's tricky to know how to include a succinct and instructive section, as the code is quite spread out and I'm not sure what part is causing this issue. I'm just setting the panels' layout as a left-justified WrapLayout.

I've included an image below which might provide some context. The image shows part of two of the three JPanels (coloured cyan) and the accompanying title JLabel for one of those JPanels (coloured green). The 1x16 grids on each panel are managed using camickr's WrapLayout. All three cyan JPanels are contained within a larger display JPanel that has then been packed into a JScrollPane (hence the grey scroller to the right of the image).

Any help would be really appreciated.

[image]

Here's another image I created that shows the issue a little more clearly. The third panel in the image wraps to a new row to display all the 1x16 grids that it contains, and in so doing, doubles the height of the other two panels, despite them not needing to resize.

[image]

Here's how I want the GUI to display:

[image]

Comment: By `WrapLayout` DYM [this layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/)?

Comment: **General Tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) I don't find that image to be very clear, could you color the different elements to distinguish where one ends and the next begins?

Comment: Hi @AndrewThompson yes, it's the layout described at the link you provided

Comment: I have amended my question to hopefully provide a little more clarification. I'm not sure what portion of code would best illustrate the potential issue, but I'm happy to share as much as required

Comment: *"I'm not sure what portion of code would best illustrate the potential issue"* Hopefully if you'd read the documents linked, you'd have realized 'enough code to show the problem without changes or additions, but not a single line more'. I'll wait till there's an MRE / SSCCE before devoting more time to this..

Comment: As I say, I'm not sure precisely where the problem area is, and am therefore unsure what portion of code would be most demonstrative, but I'll do my best to post something helpful from my code if that's what's required

Comment: BTW - by 'color the elements' I meant giving the first group of ten columns (say) red buttons, the next column green and the last 3, blue. For my part, the edited images explain even less than the original images. Now I'm just thoroughly confused about the intended effect.

Comment: *"I'm not sure precisely where the problem area is"* You haven't read the links, have you?

Comment: I understand the concepts just fine. I am looking through the code to try and isolate an independently compilable section that might help.

Comment: I have added another image to show how I'd like the panels' sizing to operate. Basically, I want each panel to be sized proportionately to the cyan JPanel they are contained by.

Comment: Judging from the desired behaviour vs the actual behaviour images, the problem probably lies in the `LayoutManager` you use to lay out the 3 panels into their parent panel/frame (which I am guessing is a `GridLayout` because the 3 panels have equally distributed sizes). If so, use some other `LayoutManager`, such as a vertical `BoxLayout`.

Comment: @gthanop, you were absolutely right - silly oversight on my part! Changed the parent's layout manager to BoxLayout using PAGE_AXIS to list vertically - works fine. Thanks very much. Ah yes, I see you suggested BoxLayout as well - thanks again.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer yet, because it was somewhat a guess, but now that it turns out that it really was the answer, should I post it as such?

Comment: Yeah, why not - even just for the suggestion of switching to BoxLayout with vertical component listing, it might be useful for anyone who encounters this issue in future.

Comment: Note: I am not sure about `PAGE_AXIS`, but maybe `Y_AXIS` instead. I shall read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the desired behaviour vs the actual behaviour images, the problem lies in the `LayoutManager` you use to lay out the 3 panels into their parent panel/frame (which I am guessing is a `GridLayout` because the 3 panels have equally distributed sizes). If so, use some other `LayoutManager`, such as a vertical `BoxLayout`.

An example code and tutorial can be found in the [Oracle's corresponding one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) (the actual code sample of which, can be found in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BoxLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BoxLayoutDemo.java) link with fancy code coloring, or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BoxLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BoxLayoutDemo.java) as plain text).

Comment: Yep, absolutely right - thanks again. BoxLayout Y_AXIS and PAGE_AXIS both seem to do the trick, but I'll go with Y_AXIS as you suggested in your comment under my original post.

Answer (score 3):

I created the following GUI.

[image: Boxes]

I created a `JFrame`.  I created one main `JPanel` to place inside the `JFrame`.  The main `JPanel` uses a `GridBaglayout` to separate three cyan `JPanels`.

Each cyan `JPanel` calculates a preferred size based on the number of black `JPanels` placed in the cyan `JPanel`.  Change the `boxesPerRow` value to get a different number of boxes per row.

Each black `JPanel` is created with a preferred size of 20 x 80 pixels;

Here's the complete runnable code.  A minimal reproducible example, in other words.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BoxesGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BoxesGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Boxes");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(createCyanPanel(1), gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(createCyanPanel(1), gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(createCyanPanel(20), gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createCyanPanel(int count) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        
        JPanel dummyPanel = createBlackPanel();
        Dimension d = dummyPanel.getPreferredSize();
        
        int boxesPerRow = 8;
        int width = (d.width + 5) * boxesPerRow + 5;
        int height = ((count + boxesPerRow - 1) / boxesPerRow) * (d.height + 5) + 5;
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            panel.add(createBlackPanel());
        }
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createBlackPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 80));
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: nice little mock-up Gilbert, thanks. I guess the only downside is, the cyan JPanels are stuck at their maximum required size after resizing the GUI window.